# ADB failed to start make sure the plugin is properly configured

Tags: android, plugins, adt

I have this problem every now and then, it says "**ADB server didn't ACK, failed to start daemon**".

So First, I followed some instructions to reset the adb in DDMS, AND then it gives me "**adb failed to start, make sure the plugin is properly configured**". 
After reading some other solutions, I kill the adb.exe in my task manager, but it became alive again after 2 seconds.

I have restart my eclipse and pc couple of times, still no luck.
anyone know whats the problem? I am using win8, don't know if it the problem...

Answer (score 10):

You can solve this issue by following below mentioned steps

1. Go to Task Manager and kill **adb.exe** from Process tab
2. Go to **DDMS->Devices** tab in eclipse and select option **Reset adb**.
3. Your emulator will come in Online and can go further.

If this should not work, try restarting Eclipse and the emulator, and try the steps again.

Comment: I already did what you have listed, check my question.

Comment: These steps are not going to help as @Jolin clearly specify in the question that these steps he/she already taken.